# WPF Ribbon - Cannot have nested BeginInit calls on the same instance

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2015, ribbon-control

Everybody,

I am stuck with a wiered issue since yesterday . 
I've searched all the forums , blah blah blah.....
No Luck Yet...

I am making a WPF windows Desktop Application using WPF Ribbon Control .
I created and deployed the whole application on my machine 
VS2015. 
Windows 8.1 64Bit.
All worked perfect.

But When I deployed it on a Windows 7-32Bit Machine.

It started throwing exception at start of the application. I've put try catch around InitializeComponents(); It throws Error 
[image: Error When I execute the installed app on Win & machine]

here is my simplified code,

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <BitmapImage x:Key="PasteImageResource" UriSource="/Images/paste.png" />
        <BitmapImage x:Key="AddImageResource" UriSource="/Images/add.png" />
    </Grid.Resources>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <DockPanel x:Name="UiPanel" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Grid.Row="1"  />



        <Ribbon x:Name="MainRibbon" RenderTransformOrigin="0.9,0.797" >

    </Ribbon>
    </Grid>
```

The problem i found is due to Ribbon Control. As soon as i remove the line (i.e)Ribbon TAg

The error goes away. I've tried to debug and found that the inner exception is saying that
    Cannot have nested BeginInit calls on the same instance

Looking for help ..........

Comment: I'm seeing the same problem with a System.Windows.Interactivity.Behavior in .Net 4.0 (!). I imagine whatever causes this is long-since fixed and I will just need to solve my problem some other way. (Upgrading is not an option.) *sigh* Oh, and hi from the future.